# Extracting types from extended generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

In Typescript, let's say we have a number of interfaces for a single model which represent the return type of different REST operations (POST, PUT, DELETE, GET all will return different fields of a single entity. For example, PUT will certainly return an object that has an ID, where DELETE would not).

So, we declared 4 interfaces for specific model: IPostUserModel, IPutUserModel, IDeleteUserModel, IGetUserModel

An abstract Service for working with this model should require generics for this:

`abstract class ModelService <IPost, IPut, IDelete, IGet>`

We want to be able to create an abstract class ModelService which would have defined 4 methods for each of these REST operations with the following signature:

```
get(id: number): IGet
post(model: Model): IPost
put(model: Model): IPut
delete(id:number): IDelete
```

**Basic situation:**

When extending this service class, we would need to specify these four interfaces:

`class UserService extends ModelService <IUserPost, IUserPut, IUserDelete, IUserGet>`

**Problem:**

If there is another class that requires some extension of BasicService class, we would need to specify its generics even though we want that class to be abstracted

```
class BasicComponent<ModelService extends BasicService>{
  /**
  * This is where it gets messy since the above line will throw an error because no generics were
  * provided for BasicService and there is no way to extract IGetModel from the ModelService even 
  * though it exists (it was needed when inheriting
  */ 
  abstract fetchData: () => IGetModel[]
}
```

**Possible Solution** (Not sure how to do in typescript):
Declare interface (or type) used to group the four interfaces and pass them as a single generic to the BasicService

```
interface IRest<POST, PUT, GET, DELETE>{
   postType: POST,
   putType: PUT,
   getType: GET,
   deleteType:DELETE
}
```

Then we could maybe do something like:

```
class BasicService<ModelWrapper extends IRest>{
    // But this also throws error above since no generics for IRest are provided
    get(id: number): typeof IRest.get
    post(model: Model): typeof IRest.post
    put(model: Model): typeof IRest.put
    delete(id:number): typeof IRest.delete
}
```

It is not a problem to declare 4 generics for specific classes when inheriting BasicService (it makes sense). But when it comes down to using a Service in BasicComponent, it is not going to work since we do not know the generics.

So, it comes down to two possible approaches:

1. Wrap all 4 interfaces in single IRest and access the types of each property
2. Somehow allow `<ModelService extends Service>` without needs for passing generics

Which one is better (and possible) and how to implement it?

Comment: Why don't you mark the fields of your model interfaces as optional like ```id?: number;```? This way you could reduce it to one interface per model.

Comment: Thank you, I have considered it, but the problem is that I need to block some of the properties on certain operations (for example, POST operation must NOT include "id" property on object)